# how to disable csrf in testing django?

Tags: django, testing, csrf

I have a problem testing views with csrf tokens.

This code

```
class ViewTests(TestCase):
    def test_bets_view(self):
        login_page = self.client.get('/users/login/')
        print(login_page.content)
```

returns HTML with CSRF hidden input.

And this thing, which I need to compare to the former HTML,

```
expected_html = render_to_response('login.html',
                                   dictionary={'form': LoginForm()})
```

doesn't have hidden CSRF input. So the assertion fails.

Ho do I disable CSRF rendering in test client?

Comment: What kind of testing are you performing? Exact matching of rendered HTML? You should be testing functionality / validation / navigation / UI (parts of it, not the whole page).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should never compare the complete HTML content. Just check the functionalities. In case you need disabling the `csrf` at any cost, following logic should help I guess.

In your `views.py` file, add the following package

`from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt`

Then just before the function definintion, in which you are performing your checks, add this snippet:

`@csrf_exempt`

This will disable the default verification of csrf. Even if your incoming request has a hidden csrf token, your server function will completely ignore it. This should do the trick of disabling the csrf.

Comment: but this doesn't disable csrf *in test client*, it does it **everywhere**, does it not?  i.e. your tests pass and you have an insecure app.  xbello's is, by far, the better approach - it tells you how to work with csrf on the test client.

Answer (score 5):

You can override your middleware settings in your unit test like this:

```
from django.test import override_settings

testing_middleware = [ ... anything but csrf middleware goes here ]


class TestWhatever(TestCase)
    @override_settings(MIDDLEWARE=testing_middleware)
    def testSomething():
        # no csrf error will occur 
        self.client.post('/', data={ ... })
```

Answer (score 2):

First you get the page in your tests and extract the csrf token from it:

```
page = self.client.get("/users/login")
token = page.context.get("csrf_token")
```

Then you use the same token to render the template and compare:

```
expected_html = TemplateResponse(
    page.wsgi_request,                                              
    "login.html",                                   
    context={"form": LoginForm(), "csrf_token": token}).render()

assert expected_html.content == page.content
```