# Django csrf token is modifying expected output and causing unit test to fail

Tags: python, django, selenium

I'm currently going through Harry Percival's Test Driven Development with Python and am having an issue with a response as soon as I add the {% csrf_token %} to my html template.

As this is test driven development, there are a couple of unit tests that are failing.

When I remove the {% csrf_token %} I get a passing test. When it exists in the code it modifies the response to include an unexpected line

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="WaPf57...">
```

which appears below the original line "

```
<body>
    <h1>Your To-Do List</h1>
        <form method="POST">
            <input name="item_text" id="id_new_item" placeholder="Enter a to-do item" />
            {% csrf_token %}
        </form>
        <table id="id_list_table">
            <tr><td>{{ new_item_text }}</td></tr>
        </table>
</body>
```

In the unit test below, I have printed out to my console the actual and expected and I received another line with the csrfmiddleware token.

```
def test_home_page_returns_correct_html(self):
    request = HttpRequest()
    response = home_page(request)
    expected_html = render_to_string('home.html')
    print('response: ', response.content.decode())
    print('expected: ', expected_html)
    self.assertEqual(response.content.decode(), expected_html)
```

Is there a way to remove that from the response or should I modify the test so that it includes all of the expected HTML and ignores the "hidden" csrfmiddlewaretoken?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983158/how-to-disable-csrf-in-testing-django/28985576

Comment: That "unexpected" output is exactly what is expected from the `{% csrf_token %}` and is an important security feature. The last thing you want to do is remove it. Unfortunately I don't know as much as I should about testing, but it strikes me that this testing process is flawed. You're not providing any context to `render_to_string`, so the only reason it works at all, I guess, is that this template doesn't use any context variables. And I don't see the value in comparing raw HTML, better to check that the right template is rendered and that the right action happens when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to mock the token generation function so it has a predictable value when you need to compare the output for equality.

For example, the code block below will ensure the html output includes `<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="predicabletoken">` instead of a random token string.

```
from unittest import mock

from django.test import TestCase


@mock.patch('django.template.context_processors.get_token', mock.Mock(return_value='predicabletoken'))
class HomeTests(TestCase):
  def test_home_page_returns_correct_html(self):
    request = HttpRequest()
    response = home_page(request)
    expected_html = render_to_string('home.html', request=request)
    print('response: ', response.content.decode())
    print('expected: ', expected_html)
    self.assertEqual(response.content.decode(), expected_html)
```

Comment: The best answer here as it compares the entire template with the output. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Great book to lean Django with! The source of your error is based on the functionality of the csrf_token tag, the docs on how it works can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#how-it-works). In short, each session has its own csrf token to make sure that the requests are coming from your webpage itself and not just POSTed to your server from elsewhere. With that in mind a request to the page and the template rendered to a string **should** have different content.

One point that you will see a lot in that book is asking yourself what is this test testing? For this case it seems that you want to check that the template rendered is the template you expect and for that you may want to do an assertion on [reponse.templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Response.templates) instead of `response.content.decode`.

If you follow that suggestion it will end up looking something like:

```
    self.assertEqual(response.templates[0].name, 'home.html')
```