# hi i am getting "CSRF Failed and CSRF cookie not set." error

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-csrf

{"detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF cookie not set."} error in postman , i am using django rest_framework for developing ios android backend .

when i first time clear all cookies and use my login api is working fine
[image]
this will give me all info about user as per my code but after that when i try to hit any api using post method its always give crsf failed.
[image]
i also use csrf_exempt decorator in view and urls.py and also tried CsrfExemptMixin from brace package.
my login code is

```
from django.contrib.auth import login,logout
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
# local py files
from .models import *
from .serializers import *
from app_apis.models import *
# third party
from rest_framework import (generics,
permissions)
from knox.views import LoginView as KnoxLoginView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.authtoken.serializers import AuthTokenSerializer
from knox.models import AuthToken
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from braces.views import CsrfExemptMixin
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token
# Register API

class RegisterView(CsrfExemptMixin,generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class=RegisterUserSerializer
    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def post(self,request,*args, **kwargs):
        serializer=self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        print
        logout(request)
        return Response({
        "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
        "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
        })


class LoginAPI(CsrfExemptMixin,KnoxLoginView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    def get(self,request):
        example={
    "username":"user_name",
    "password":"Your Password" 
    }
        return Response(example)
    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = AuthTokenSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        user_id_main=user.id
        user_name=user.username
        user_data=[user_id_main,user_name]
        print(user_data)
        projects=ProjectTable.objects.filter(created_by_id=user_id_main).values_list('name')
        project_names=projects
        login(request, user)
        temp_list=super(LoginAPI, self).post(request, format=None)
        temp_list.data["project_list"]=project_names
        temp_list.data["user_data"]=user_data
        temp_list.data['csrf_token']=get_token(request)
        return Response({"data":temp_list.data})

# logout
def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect("user_profile:login")
```

please guide me . thanks in advance

Comment: from what I can tell the issue is postman isn't getting the CSRF token. I believe there is a setting to disable CSRF tokens during test. The other option to to do a `GET` call then parse out the CSRF token. Best bet is the first option. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983158/how-to-disable-csrf-in-testing-django

Comment: thanks for your comment but in my case  'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    # 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
]    now it is working but i don't know how .

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication` in `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`

Reference link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56101653/217586

Answer (score 1):

use corsheaders in installed app  https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/ use and follow the documentation